# SELECT hex(name || age) AS X FROM Ages ORDER BY X

Tags: sql, sqlite, hex

I am taking a Cousera course talking about SQL and there is one line of code I cannot understand.

What does it mean by 'hex(name || age)'? I know it turns the string into hexadecimal format using the hex() function, but what does 'name || age' do? I cannot find any document about the '||' operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`||` is the SQLite concatenation operator.  So `hex(name || age)` will pass a concatenated string of `name` and `age` into the `hex()` function.

From the SQLite [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

> The hex() function interprets its argument as a BLOB and returns a string which is the upper-case hexadecimal rendering of the content of that blob.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#collateop) says:

> The **||** operator is "concatenate" - it joins together the two strings of its operands.

Answer (score 0):

|| is the pipe or concat operator which would concatenate two strings E.g. if name is PREETI and age is 25 'name || age' would be PREETI25

Answer (score 0):

It converts the Strings into Hexadecimal using hex() and then it would concatenate the two strings using || operators and then returns the hexadecimal form of the concatenated  Strings .

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work in MYSQL:

```
SELECT
    HEX(CONCAT(name, age)) AS X

FROM Ages

ORDER BY X
```